# Java Buttons, Action Events & Listeners

Tags: java, for-loop, button, actionlistener, actionevent

I'm currently working on a GUI for a Project Management system.

Can't figure out how to get the Action Event to work correctly.

The following lines of code are what i'm using for the two.

```
    public  JPanel setupButtons(User u){

        JPanel forButtons = new JPanel();
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        for(int i = 0; i != u.projectSize(); i++){
            this.jRdBttn = new JRadioButton(u.getProject(i).getName());
            forButtons.add(jRdBttn);
            group.add(jRdBttn);

            jRdBttn.addActionListener(this);
            jRdBttn.setEnabled(true);
        }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getSource() == select){
            if(this.jRdBttn.isSelected()){
                System.out.println("It worked!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just need to figure out the problem i'm having with the action listener & Action Event.

Comment: *"Just need to figure out the problem i'm having with the action listener & Action Event."* Well could you tell us what this problem is maybe? That would be helpful.

Comment: Okay so the action event isn't actually doing anything. I just need to get them to work, so that i can get it to create more buttons based on another for-loop, that basically reuses the same code

Comment: What is that select variable you use in `if(e.getSource() == select)`?

Comment: That is a different button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that's all the code that has anything to do with your `ActionListener`, here's your answer:

You give all your `RadioButtons` an `ActionListener`. Which will then of course be called when **THE RADIO BUTTONS** get pressed. 
However, in those cases, the source of the event will **never** be that other button called `select`.

You seem to want to call your `ActionListener` when the `select` button is pressed. Which means that is the button that needs an `ActionListener` and not your `RadioButtons`.

As a side note:

```
this.jRdBttn = new JRadioButton(u.getProject(i).getName());
```

This will mean that `this.jRdBttn` will only contain the very last `RadioButton` you created at the end of that loop. All others will be lost forever as you have no more direct references to them (of course you still actually have them in your component hierarchy, but it's kind of a pain to ever use them again that way).

--- Edit 29.05.2018 ---

If you wanted to react every time a radio button is clicked (which is what I think you mean with your comment) without any need for a select button, there would be multiple ways to achieve this.

Which way you use very much depends on your use case.

If we try to stay as close to your current approach as we can, we might need to store all your RadioButtons in an array and then iterate through that array to find the currently selected button.
You wouldn't even need to look at the ActionEvent or it's source, as you don't really care which RadioButton was just pressed, only which one is currently selected.

Of course, you could argue that the button that was just pressed IS the one that was selected, but with your current approach you'd still have to iterate through the array to find the index (which I assume you might need to access the corresponding project), which basically renders it pointless.

So first step: In your class, add this:

```
private JRadioButton[] radioButtons;
```

Next:

```
public  JPanel setupButtons(User u){

    JPanel forButtons = new JPanel();
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtons = new JRadioButton[u.projectSize()]; // <- This is new

    for(int i = 0; i != u.projectSize(); i++){
        radioButtons[i] = new JRadioButton(u.getProject(i).getName());
        forButtons.add(radioButtons[i]);
        group.add(radioButtons[i]);

        radioButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
        radioButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

And last but not least:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
         if (radioButtons[i].isSelected()) {
             System.out.println("Button " + i + " was selected!");
             // Optionally, you might want to put a break; here
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if i remove the select button, how would i be able to use all buttons generated by for-loop

Comment: Thank you so much.